# Build flutter module to aar,but the local flutter plugin is missing #138971

Tags: flutter, flutter-module

every one :).
In my case, I have a flutter module, which used by an android project, when need to build an apk，I will build the flutter module to aar first`flutter build aar --no-debug --no-profile -v`,then copy the aar files`flutter_module/build/host/outputs/repo` to the android project.
The flutter module also contains other plugins,like [flutter_blue_plus: ^1.15.8](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus),It always works ok when I build aar.
Then the problem is coming when I create a local flutter plugin package and use it in the flutter module,the local plugin also contains android native code.

```
my_flutter_plugin:
    path: ../my_flutter_plugin
```

,if I use the flutter module in source code mode,it also works ok,but if I build the flutter module to aar as usual,the aar files don't have the local package plugin in it!
I have checked the generated aar files,in the ../flutter_release/1.0/flutter_release-1.0.pom,I found it contains the local plugins dependency

```
 
# <dependency>
#       <groupId>com.flutter.plugin.my_flutter_plugin</groupId>
#       <artifactId>my_flutter_plugin_release</artifactId>
#       <version>1.0</version>
#       <scope>compile</scope>
#     </dependency>
#     <dependency>
      <groupId>com.lib.flutter_blue_plus</groupId>
      <artifactId>flutter_blue_plus_release</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

but in the *.aar files, there's have no anything about the flutter local plugin,I don't konw what's wrong with it,could anyone help me?Thank you so much.

By the way,the published plugin flutter_blue_plus works ok,it not only contains in the flutter_release-1.0.pom,but also contains flutter_blue_plus_release-1.0.aar file.

I hope when I build the flutter module to aar,it also could package the local flutter plugin into it.

Comment: I have resolved this problem for temprory by change 
my_flutter_plugin:
    path: ../my_flutter_plugin
to 
my_flutter_plugin:
     git:
      url: https://gitlab.xxx.xx/xxx/flutter/my_flutter_plugin.git
      ref: master